# How to convert two tables with same columns to one adding count and groupping by third table

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregation

I have two tables with same columns: products and prices for them.

Table 1:

table 1:

```
Product   Price
---------------
name1      1
name2      3
name3      4
name1      2
```

Table 2:

```
Product   Price
---------------
name1      1
name3      2
name4      5
name3      3
```

Also I have table with Products only:

Table 3:

```
Product
--------
name1
name2
name3
name4
```

I want to take out sum of prices and amount of same products from each table separately grouped by product names.

I've tried to use join and union in order to make table, but all I have is table with single values or make the right table with wrong result, like if there was doublled results.

```sql
select t3.product as _product, sum(t1.price) as _t1Sum, count(t1.price) as _t1Count, sum(t2.price) as _t2Sum, count(t2.price) as _t2Count
from Table3 as t3,
     Table1 as t1 
  full join Table2 as t2 on t1.product = t2.product
where (t3.product = t1.product or t3.product = t2.product)
group by _product
```

Using `union` or `union all` I've got table with 3 columns.
Using any kind of join I've got table with 5 columns and duplicate results, like if there was 3 name3 products in both columns Table_Sum.

Example of result table I want:

```
Product     Table1_Sum    Table1_Amount   Table2_Sum  Table2_Amount
-------------------------------------------------------------------
name1         3               2             1            1
name2         3               1             0            0
name3         4               1             5            2
name4         0               0             5            1
```

How do I edit my query to make table like example?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: you should not mix implicit joins (in the where clause) and explicit `JOIN` operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ea27d9f6f30ec6ed708a5b7b0c36fb1b)

---

**1. way**: You can use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT
    p.product,
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(price), 0) FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.product = p.product),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.product = p.product),
    (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(price), 0) FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.product = p.product),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.product = p.product)
FROM
    products p
```

**2. way**: You can group before joining:

```
SELECT
    p.product,
    COALESCE(t1.sum, 0) AS t1_sum,
    COALESCE(t1.count, 0) AS t1_cnt,
    COALESCE(t2.sum, 0) AS t2_sum,
    COALESCE(t2.count, 0) AS t2_cnt
FROM
    products p
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT product, SUM(price), COUNT(*) FROM table1 GROUP BY product) t1
    ON t1.product = p.product
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT product,SUM(price), COUNT(*) FROM table2 GROUP BY product) t2
    ON t2.product = p.product
```

The `COALESCE()` function sets the result to `0` if there is none.